# Person body parts segmentation using python (BodyPix)

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation, bodypix

I need to segment person body parts, and I found BodyPix [segmentPersonPart](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/body-pix) to be very helpful, but Its not included in the python implementation of it. I am just wondering if there are any other similar functions as i didn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

Python implementation of BodyPix is available at [python-tf-bodypix](https://github.com/de-code/python-tf-bodypix)